# Vibrator.vibrate() does nothing in Android 10 Pie if the app is not active in focus

Tags: android

I have a background service that works just fine: it starts up on boot and does what it needs to do. It receives Firebase notifications and stores them; it also send a “delivery confirmation” entry to the same Firebase database.

Except that since I got a new Pixel 2 running Android 10 Pie, the vibration doesn’t happen. The database entry is created, so we’re not dealing with a background-process-being-killed-thing. It’s simply that the call to vibrator doesn’t work. Everything else does.

Android 7.1 is the last physical device I have on hand to confirm how it should work. As of Android 10 on the Pixel 2, the vibrator just doesn’t... vibrate.

Any workarounds I could try?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Here is the possible solution, that worked for me:

```java
private final long VIBRO_TIME = 1000L;
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

if (vibrator.hasVibrator()) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()                            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                            .build();
        VibrationEffect ve = VibrationEffect.createOneShot(VIBRO_TIME,
                            VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE);
        vibrator.vibrate(ve, audioAttributes);
    } else {
        vibrator.vibrate(VIBRO_TIME);
    }
}
```